# C#, Making a collection of class fields

Tags: c#, collections, properties, field

Is there a way to make a collection of existing class fields?

I have a class with a lot of fields/properties of various types with meaningful names.

```
class ExampleClass
{
   public string meaningfulName1 { get; set;}
   public double meaningfulName2 { get; set;}
   ...
   public myOtherClass meaningfulNameN { get; set;}
}
```

I need to read values for those properties from a file, generated in external (not mine) program.

As there're a lot of fields/properties, reading values and assigning them one by one seems inefficient. So I want a collection of those fields/properties. Something like

```
foreach (fieldReference in ExampleClass.fieldReferenceCollection)
{
   readValueFromFile(fieldReference);
}
```

But how do I make one while keeping all the names?

Making a collection with all the parameters values instead of separate fields seems logical, but field names would be lost then. And, given the number of fields, we'd like to keep those names if possible to simplify further development.

So I need separate fields/properties AND a collection of them to be available at the same time.

Dictionary collection is not exactly fast, afaik, so parameter names as keys for values doesn't seem exactly fitting too.

Another option I found is reflection, but I'm not yet sure how the order of fields in reflected collection is determined. Order of fields is very important as the file, I'm reading values from, has no metadata, just a sequence of hex values. Also reflection seems to be overkill for reading values from a file, and it is slow too, afaik.

So the question is: what should I do in order to have class fields and a collection of them at the same time?

Are my assumptions wrong about this task? Is there any other approach to reading a lot of dumb values from a file into a complex object?

P.S. My first SO question and English is my very second language, so I'm sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: Rather than just assuming the solutions are too slow, write them and find out if they're too slow.  If they are *then* you can look at how to address those problems, if not, you have your solution.

Comment: What type of file are you reading from?  XML, JSON, INI?  There might already be a parser depending on what you are working with.

Comment: Is Reflection slower than disk I/O? I'd try. About order: it's not something (declaration order) you should use, just add an attribute on each property and order them with it.

Comment: Reflection is about 2-4x slower than normal get/set, but probably not too slow. GetFields() does not return fields in declaration or alphabetical order so you'd have to do that some other way.

Comment: Can you show the sample data from the file your program will be reading?

Comment: @juharr LabView flattened data file. Couldn't find a freely available parser.

Comment: @vendettamit I'm not sure why, but it begins with the following hex sequence 00 00 16 84 00 00 00 0a 00 00 04 71 40 34 00 00 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you would have to use reflection to do what you want.  As for determining the order of the fields, I suggest tagging the properties with a custom attribute.

Here's an example.  Hope this leads you to the solution you need.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class FileField : Attribute
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public FileField() { }
    }
    class ExampleClass
    {
        [FileField(Index = 0)]
        public string meaningfulName1 { get; set; }
        [FileField(Index = 2)]
        public double meaningfulName2 { get; set; }
        [FileField(Index = 1)]
        public MyOtherClass meaningfulNameN { get; set; }
    }
    class MyOtherClass
    {
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var exampleClassFieldProperties = GetExampleClassFieldProperties();

            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("datafile.txt");
            var records = new List<ExampleClass>();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var fields = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var record = new ExampleClass();
                for(int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < fields.Length; fieldIndex++)
                {
                    if (exampleClassFieldProperties.ContainsKey(fieldIndex))
                    {
                        ReadValueFromFile(fields[fieldIndex], exampleClassFieldProperties[fieldIndex], record);
                    }
                }
                records.Add(record);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static Dictionary<int, PropertyInfo> GetExampleClassFieldProperties()
        {
            var exampleClassFieldProperties = new Dictionary<int, PropertyInfo>();

            var properties = typeof(ExampleClass).GetProperties();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(false);
                int index = 0;
                foreach (var attribute in attributes)
                {
                    if (attribute is FileField)
                    {
                        index = ((FileField)attribute).Index;
                        if (exampleClassFieldProperties.ContainsKey(index) == false)
                        {
                            exampleClassFieldProperties.Add(index, property);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return exampleClassFieldProperties;
        }
        public static void ReadValueFromFile(string field, PropertyInfo exampleClassField, ExampleClass record)
        {
            if (exampleClassField.PropertyType.Name == typeof(string).Name)
            {
                record.GetType().InvokeMember(exampleClassField.Name,
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
                    Type.DefaultBinder, record, new object[] { field });
            }
            else if (exampleClassField.PropertyType.Name == typeof(double).Name)
            {
                record.GetType().InvokeMember(exampleClassField.Name,
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
                    Type.DefaultBinder, record, new object[] { double.Parse(field) });
            }
            else if (exampleClassField.PropertyType.Name == typeof(MyOtherClass).Name)
            {
                var other = new MyOtherClass();
                // TO DO: Parse field to set properties in MyOtherClas
                record.GetType().InvokeMember(exampleClassField.Name,
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
                    Type.DefaultBinder, record, new object[] { other });
            }
        }
    }
}
```